# Integrating Factor Method. Why Can We Set the Constant of Integration to Zero?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My textbook gives a demonstration of the use of the integrating factor method for solving first order ordinary differential equations:

$\dfrac{dx}{dt} + p(t)x = r(t)$

$\implies g(t)\dfrac{dx}{dt} + g(t)p(t)x = g(t)r(t)$

$\dfrac{d}{dt}[g(t)x]$

We use the product rule and compare the expression to the left-hand side of the above equation:

$g(t)\dfrac{dx}{dt} + \dfrac{dg}{dt}x = g(t)\dfrac{dx}{dt}+g(t)p(t)x$

$\therefore \dfrac{dg}{dt} = g(t)p(t)$

The above equation is separable.

$\therefore \int\dfrac{dg}{g(t)} = \int p(t) dt$

$\implies ln[g(t)] = \int p(t)dt$

My textbook then says that, "We can set the constant of integration to zero -- any function that satisfies $\dfrac{dg}{dt} = g(t)p(t)$ will do for our purposes". However, it gives no explanation as to why this is the case. Why can we set the constant of integration to zero? Why is any function that satisfied $\dfrac{dg}{dt} = g(t)p(t)$ appropriate for our purposes?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to elaborate on this.

Comment: That constant doesn't make a difference. The constant of integration in integrating factor appears on both sides as factor, and cancels out.

Comment: @samjoe Can you please show me what you're describing?

Comment: The constant of integration, say C, will lead to a factor $e^C$ in line 2 of your question which can simply be cancelled out on both sides of that equation.

Comment: @Paul Could you please demonstrate what you're describing?

Comment: See answer comment.

Comment: Notice they solve the equation only with the knowledge that $\frac{dg}{dt} = g(t)p(t)$, and they don't have to elaborate on what $g(t)$ is to solve it. As such, it's pretty obvious that any $g$ will work. I'm sure your textbook continues with the example, you can add the $C$ into the finished equation to understand it's effect.

Answer (score 1):

Integration Factor = $g(t) = \exp(\int p(t)dt) = \exp(P(t)+c) = \exp(P(t))\cdot\exp(c)$, where $P(t)$ is the antiderivative of $p(t)$.

Solution of LDE is:

$$x\cdot(\exp(P(t)+c)) = \int \exp(P(t)+c)\cdot r(t)dt$$

This factor $\exp(c)$ is cancelled from both sides! Paul has already elaborated thanks!

Comment: Where is the other $e^c$ that it cancels out with? I only see one in your calculations.

Comment: Oh i edited the answer, the factor appears on both the sides, ends up being cancelled.

Comment: Sorry, I must be completely misunderstanding something. Could you please further clarify your point?

Comment: $g(t)\frac{dx}{dt}+g(t)p(t)x=g(t)r(t)$. If $g(t) = e^{P+c}=e^{P}e^{c}$ then  $e^{P}e^{c}\frac{dx}{dt}+e^{P}e^{c}p(t)x=e^{P}e^{c}r(t)$ and since $e^{c}$ cannot be zero we can divide through by it to get $e^{P}\frac{dx}{dt}+e^{P}p(t)x=e^{P}r(t)$.

Comment: @Paul Thank you very much for the assistance. I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to clarify what $g(t)$ actually is in order to solve the DE, all it requires is that $\frac{dg}{dt} = g(t)p(t)$ is satisfied. As such, any $g$ should do, and so why not use the cleanest one?

Let $\int p(t) dt = P(t) + C$. It turns out that: $$g(t) = e^{P(t) + C} = e^Ce^{P(t)}$$
If you plug this into the original differential equation, you can divide out by $e^C$ and the product rule can still be set up. As such, $C = 0$ works, and again, is easiest.