# Analytic solution to ODE: $\frac{dy}{dt} = -100y +100t +1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given an ODE like the following:

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = -100y +100t +1$$

What's the best approach to solve it?

I tried Mathematica and it returns:

$$y(t) = t + e^{-100t} C$$

Comment: What approaches have you tried?

Comment: Solve the homogenous system first and then use variation of constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $ x = y - t$, so the equation becomes
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} + 1 &= -100x +1 \\
\frac{dx}{dt} &= -100x.
\end{align}
Implying that for some constant $c$,
\begin{align}
x(t) &= c\cdot e^{-100t}\\ &\text{i.e.}\\ 
x(t) &= x(0)\cdot e^{-100t}.
\end{align}
Since $y = x + t$, we get that $y(0) = x(0)$, so the answer is $$y(t) = y(0)\cdot e^{-100t} + t.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a first order linear differential equation.

This means, the solution has the form $$y = y_h + y_p$$

where $y_h$ is the solution of the homogeneous DE $y' + 100y = 0$ and $y_p$ is a particular solution.

We solve the homogeneous DE:

$y' = -100y \iff dy/y = -100 dt \iff \ln|y| = -100t +c \iff y = c e^{-100t}$

For the particular solution, we suggest $y_p = At + B$

Filling this in the original DE yields:

$A = -100At - 100B + 100t + 1$

or equivalently:

$$\begin{cases} A = 1 - 100B \\ -100A + 100 = 0 \end{cases}$$
$$\iff \begin{cases} A = 1 \\B = 0 \end{cases}$$

Therefore, $y_p = t$

Hence, $$y(t) = Ce^{-100t} + t$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that it is a first-order linear ordinary nonhomogeneous differential equation, therefore you can solve it using an [integrating factor](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx):
$$\frac{dy}{dt}+100y=100t+1$$

> Note that given a linear ODE in the form:
>   $$\frac{dy}{dt}+p(t)y=q(t)$$
>   Then $\mu(t)=e^{\int p(t)~dt}$ is the integrating factor.

Therefore, in our case, we have:
$$\mu(t)=e^{\int 100~dt}=e^{100t}$$
Note that the constant of integration on the integrating factor is [not necessary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174285/integrating-factor-method-why-can-we-set-the-constant-of-integration-to-zero). Hence:
$$e^{100t}\frac{dy}{dt}+100e^{100t}y=e^{100t}(100t+1)$$
You can now substitute $100e^{100t}=\frac{d}{dt}(e^{100t})$, and then use the reverse product rule. Hence, we have:
$$\frac{d}{dt}(e^{100t}y)=e^{100t}(100t+1)$$
Hence, if we integrate both sides with respect to $t$, we obtain:
$$\int \frac{d}{dt}(e^{100t}y)~dt=\int e^{100t}(100t+1)~dt$$
All that remains to do is evaluate these integrals.